# How to save and share a layout in jpeg format on roomle?

Tags: roomle

I have a professional subscription of Roomle? I have read that a layout can be saved as jpeg in high resolution but I can’t find any option anywhere.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: The layout which I have made on Roomle. I want to save it as jpeg in high resolution. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Roomle SDK you can use `preparePerspectiveImage` ([link](https://docs.roomle.com/web/api/classes/roomleconfigurator.html#prepareperspectiveimage)) to generate an image.

If you are using the Embedding Lib you can listen to `onRequestProduct` ([link](https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#listen-to-onrequestproduct)) which will contain the image as Base64.

In case you just want to render an image without an integration you can use the feature in Rubens admin ([link](https://docs.roomle.com/web/datamanagement/products.html#request-renderings)). This feature is only available for level 2 customers and above.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very helpful?